# What is the best way to replace a piece of the exe's file content in Windows and then run it?

Tags: windows, bash, file

I want to create a copy of some exe file, edit its piece of code(note: not just a single line), save it and run it

Let's assume I have a executable file program.exe with the following content:

```
a
bb
ccc
dddd
eeeee
```

And I want to create a duplicate of that file, replace a piece of content and run.

Please note I want to replace a piece of content, not just a single line.

So for example I want to replace this part:

```
bb
ccc
dddd
```

with:

```
xxx
yyy
```

So in the end the final content should look like:

```
a
xxx
yyy
eeeee
```

On Unix system I will use sh script for that. What will be the best choice for Windows?

Comment: I'm confused with the `.exe` part. Replacing strings in a binary executable isn't done easily.

Comment: Please treat it like every other readable file then. I have an exe file containing part of human-readable text that I want to modify every time.

Comment: Does it work when you edit it manually?

Comment: Yes. I do it every day. For some reason the file is being updated independently of me Then after the update, I have to manually open the file in notepad, find the lines and change the content. I want to automatize it.

Comment: Have you actually done this using a sh script in Unix? Because I really don't think it's suitable without a specialized tool. If you do know how though, then download a port such as MinGW, Cygwin, or similar and work with the tools you already know. Generally speaking, editing exes is not like editing text files, as you may need to fix addresses and metadata in the file to accommodate your changes and it's best to familiarize yourself with the documentation.

Comment: I didn't achieve this in Unix, because this problem exists only on Windows and the goal of the question is to find a tool that can help me with it similarly like it was a problem on Unix where I can easily do it with the sh script.

Comment: I am not editing any machine code. I have a human-readable part in my exe that I want to modify. This question is not related to exe file type, this is just additional info in case if opening text file or exe file differs somehow.

Comment: Basically you want to modify part of some non-text (i.e. binary file) on Windows. Whether this is EXE format or something else does not matter. You could do it with any programming language which allows you to open a file for reading and writing. Nearly any language will do, but the ones requiring least work are probably languages with don't need a complicated compiling/linking process - for instance Ruby, Python or Perl. Even on Unix, I would likely not use `sh`  for this task.

Comment: But if you **really** prefer to do this with _sh_ (POSIX shell), you can do this in Windows too: Install Cygwin - the base package and then `dash`. The _dash_ shell is very close to Bourne shell you know from Unix.

Comment: For one, you can't simply edit "hello world" to "example" as you'd wind up with "exampleorld". You need to know the offset and length of what you want to overwrite, and then you overwrite it either with something of the exact same byte length, or in a format with a definite end. Eg: null-terminated string. For two, this would invalidate any signature on the file and cause Windows to raise warning about it. Also, this is utterly unhinged. You should have the program load a config file that you edit, because modifying the binary like this every day is frankly just nuts.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

perl -p0e 's/bb[\n\r]+ccc[\n\r]+dddd/xxx
yyy/' program.exe
```

I have tested on the test data in your post. You need to do proper escaping if your data contains special characters. Also I use `[\n\r]+` for it to work on both Windows and Linux.